# WSO2 ESB Integrator - While doing Maven build on proxy service

Tags: wso2, maven-plugin, wso2-esb

Am having the integrator service (proxy service) in which local-entry is getting used. Now when am trying to do the maven build on the service, am getting following error on the build.

```
    ESB Local Entry plugin dependency added in pom.xml:

<groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>wso2-esb-localentry-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.13</version>


Error:

[ERROR]   The project com.xx.xx.SubmissionService.local-entry:XMLStringEncoder:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT (xx/xx/xx/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.wso2.maven:maven-localentry-plugin:2.0.13 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.wso2.maven:maven-localentry-plugin:jar:2.0.13 in nexus (xx) -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: synapse/local-entry @ line 8, column 14


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (package) on project xxService: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (package) on project xxService: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)


Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:276)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)


Can some one please help me to resolve the issue.


Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda old question, but maybe someone has similar problem. You must add a plugin to your .pom file, not a dependency. Try adding below code to the pom file of the project (or subproject) containing local-entry files. It should do the job.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>wso2-esb-localentry-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>proxy</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>pom-gen</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactLocation>.</artifactLocation>
            <typeList>${artifact.types}</typeList>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration/>
</plugin>
```